# How can I make a 3D wireframe object hollow?

Tags: python, wireframe

For instance, if I want to make a wireframe snowman out of three spheres, I would like to trim the spheres so that only the outermost surfaces are shown. That is, if sphere 1 and sphere 2 overlap, I'd like to delete the overlap region of both spheres. And is there a way to do this automatically with, say a python script, given the coordinates and radii of the spheres? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try a boolean modifier. Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5752/599

Comment: You could use the boolean, or if you're rendering with cycles, a special shader.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't necessary to use python, you can use *[Boolean modifiers](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Booleans)* to do this.

Add a boolean modifier to one of the spheres for every other sphere which intersects with it:

[image]

Then apply all the modifiers either by click *apply* for each one, or by pressing <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> *> Convert to mesh*.

Result:

[image]