# Delete all interior vertices,faces, edges of a 3D model

Tags: selection-tools

I basically have a similar setup like in this example:

[Simplify mesh by cutting out inside parts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5752/simplify-mesh-by-cutting-out-inside-parts)

I did not use particle, but the outcome is the same a lot of objects that I want to merge into one and where I want to get rid of everything that is not on the outside surface. I tried select visible like excellently described here:

[How can inner parts of a mesh be selected?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8822/how-can-inner-parts-of-a-mesh-be-selected)

But even after a long time where I carefully tried to select everything (vertices) and I inverted the selection and deleted it, it leaves me with a model with big holes.

Is there any way including exporting and using other software (Meshmixer did also not work, even though it has a similar select visible in the modify panel) where I can just select every face, vertices and edge on the outside surface of an object and then invert and delete ? Or any other way to achieve the same ?
Maybe via the Normals ?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure, but you could try to use your current shape, resulting from the union of several separate shapes, as a "model" for another object, subdivided enough, to "wrap" around, using shrinkwrap modifier... to exemplify, just like a glove fits around your hand)... without seeing your actual shape, I can't guess if it will work.