# delete overlapped part of faces

Tags: edit-mode

[image: some part is overlapped]
  
I have more than a thousand places where this happens in a single mesh object. As you can see in the image, part of the faces are overlapping. I want to delete the overlapped part of the faces.  
  
Boolean modifier won't work because it's a single mesh that has many places where this happens.  
  
Remesh modifier won't work because it creates big blobs of new mesh were there doesn't exist anything.   
  
Blender doesn't recognize that as an "interior face" too so the seletect "interior faces" and delete method won't work either. How do I delete the overlapped part of the faces?

Comment: remesh worked for me on this simple model. How complex is your actual model? Or do you mean that you want to keep the mesh separated entities with the intersecting faces removed?

Comment: sorry I only put one problem remesh caused, it wasn't the important one, I edited the post.

Comment: Perhaps uploading a simplified .blend to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ will help to further inspect and find a solution.

Comment: for remesh you have to tune the amount of detail levels to fit the mesh you are trying to clean up. Honestly not the best choice, but I would think a manual clean up is unavoidable if you have a huge scene.

Comment: Unfortunately, in Blender you can't delete "part" of a face. What you'll have to do is divide the faces that overlap into two faces each, with the division edge of one face in the same plane as the end of the other face. Then you can delete the faces that adjoin.

Comment: You could try using *Intersect* tool. In Edit mode, with all selected press `Ctrl`+`F` > *intersect* and choose *Self-Intersect* in Last Operator menu. Note though that it will work if meshes actually intersect and aren't just placed near each other. Also it may (and likely will) create zero-area faces and double vertices. So the mesh still will have a lot of to clean-up See also - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5752/simplify-mesh-by-cutting-out-inside-parts

Comment: You can't really ask for a magic tool that will adapt to your own particular way of modeling. And also magic answers because we don't know how you have been proceeding, why do you have this problem multiple times in your mesh ? Are you duplicating parts of the mesh ? If so then you should set up your first model so that when you link all your pieces together they can be nicely joined with a 'remove doubles'.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no one-klick method for this and every possible way to pull this off requires a decent amount of work. Let's break down what we actually can do with the limited information about your model/scene you provide.

Let's assume (by the look of the screenshots) that your model is a minecraft-like structure where the original blocks (before joining) only touch each other's faces and never intersect and they also don't have merged vertices. What we then *can* do with this, is separating the model into individual primitives quite easily.

Tab into edit mode, hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select everything, then <kbd>P</kbd> to start separating and select "by loose parts" in the menu.

[image: separate mesh]

Now, that we have separate blocks we could try combining the meshes step by step using the boolean modifier with the union operator.

The bad news is that the boolean modifier might not work as expected on many occasions (if you have mesh intersections or the meshes simply have no connecting faces...) and with "more than a thousand" partly hidden faces this method will be so much work that you easily could reconstruct your model from scratch as well.

Answer (score 0):

***Update***

There's an awesome new "Voxel" remesh feature in Blender 2.83 Beta / 2.90 Alpha. It will merge geometry intersections and get rid of interior faces (elements must be in a single mesh object). Voxel remesh gives it a slightly softened and beveled edges / intersection look but use another remesh modifier after it like Remesh “Blocks” or maybe a Decimate based on face angles etc to get rid of slightly beveled intersections. Finally, apply modifiers, and snap vertices to grid (may need to adjust global grid size).

*End of update*

Might have some good news for ya! So I just tried using Knife project to add extra seams where the boxes meet. The only reason we are making cuts, is so we can then merge overlapping vertices (W, "Remove Doubles") which will form the face inside that we want to delete. Then we can take advantage of a selection tool "Select" "Interior Faces", and finally delete "Faces Only".

Even if you scene is very dense, this technique will save you much more time than doing it by hand. You can begin to plan for and create different knife projection meshes to cut different groups. You can even reuse knife project meshes. Once you make your cuts, and merge doubles, you can let the Select Interior Faces tool do the hardest part, and then delete Faces Only.

You can see what the cut did in the image below (including some triangulation of a couple of faces but you can easily fix that with Alt+J which converts triangles to quads):
[image]

To use Knife Project, I had to join the boxes into one object (Ctrl + J), and then I needed a separate plane object that would serve as the projected knife. Line up the plane perfectly using snapping, so cuts line up with the existing vertices. Then, select the plane in object mode, and Shift select the combined box object. Enter Edit mode, and your boxes will now be in Edit Mode, while your selected plane stays in object mode. Change your view to Orthorgraphic, and Front or Side (which ever lines the plane up to cut the boxes right.

If you have rotated your boxes to some odd degree that does not line up with global front, side, or top views, you can still line up your view with Shift + NumPad7 (or + NumPad3 or + NumPad1) while a face is selected. This will align your view to the top/side/front relative to the normal of that selected face. This is an amazing shortcut that can help you precision model on faces that are at odd angles not lined up with global front, side, or top views. Be sure that your plane is lined up exactly for best cutting results. Make use of snapping tools as needed. Do your cut while in Orthographic mode, and check the box "Cut Through" under the Knife Tool Sidebar (it only appears after you click Knife Project).

Once you have your cut perfect, while your boxes are in Edit Mode, press "W", "Remove Doubles".

Finally, there is a lovely tool we can use to automatically select internal faces like the one we just made. From the menu, choose Select, Interior Faces (or spacebar and type "Select Interior Faces"). Now you can delete them with "X" "Faces Only". I hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: select interior face don't always work. And the original question is that is there a easy way to do this, he has indicated he has thousands of these similar situation , and if it's done by hand on each part is tedious. His question is about automating the process.

Comment: Yeah I can see how Select Interior Faces doesn't seem to work when I tried it on a more complex model with interior faces at odd angles. At least, my method MIGHT work if he gets his cuts EXACT. This really is a tough problem.