# Delete All Internal Geometry

Tags: modeling, mesh

I generated a bunch of random cubes from MATLAB as .STL and imported into Blender. All cubes intersect so there's a bunch of internal geometry. I did ctrl-F -> intersect to create edges between cubes, but now how do I remove all the vertices/edges/faces inside the cubes?

I checked out [Simplify mesh by cutting out inside parts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5752/simplify-mesh-by-cutting-out-inside-parts) and tried to remeshing modifier, which did absolutely nothing possibly b/c I'm noob with this software, and tried the code which failed on line 4.

I'm used to using CAD, so could I possibly make an enclosure, boolean subtract from said enclosure, then fill the enclosure up with a second solid that doesn't have internals? Can Blender do that? Help!

[image]

Edit: Figured it out. Bool tool solved all my problems. Regular boolean would take forever to implement for something like this I think.

Comment: Check this out http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/71687/2517

Comment: Works, though it only cuts the edges for one cube b/w that and another. Also, how would you do this for all cubes? I tried selecting all edges and it says no intersections found.

Comment: have you tried selecting all visible faces, then invert selection and delete?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. How do I select all external faces since there are many cubes inside that I can't see? box select + select>more? Would take a while.

Comment: I think I got all the visible faces using above method, but why is it that if I select sharp edges, the intersecting edges formed from ctrl+F don't get highlighted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing internal geometry](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71687/removing-internal-geometry)

Answer (score 4):

Bool Tool Addon (fast enabled)
<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> after separating cubes using <kbd>P</kbd>*> by loose parts* in edit mode.

Comment: This is the easiest method I have found in my brief search and testing to date. If you continue to struggle with internal faces showing up, there is a more robust method that I have found in this answer here that uses the Booltron add-on "Slice" feature with a cube object as a container: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5752/simplify-mesh-by-cutting-out-inside-parts/78111#78111